# Converting a synchronous function to be async

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

As I was implementing service worker subscriptions, I noticed a message from Visual Studio Code, that the following function can be converted to be an `async` function:

[image]

Here is the my original synchronous code.

```js
/**
 * Returns the subscription if it is present, or nothing
 */
function getUserSubscription() {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(function (serviceWorker) {
      return serviceWorker.pushManager.getSubscription();
    })
    .then(function (pushSubscription) {
      return pushSubscription;
    });
}
```

I'm not sure how I'd convert this to be an `async` function. I thought I understood the gist of it, as in converting something like this:

```js
fetchData()
  .then(process())
  .then(processAgain());
```

to this:

```js
const response1 = await fetchData();
const response2 = await process(response1);
const response = await processAgain(response2);
```

But I've had no luck converting my function using this technique.

Comment: Just add the keyword `async` to make `async function getUserSubscription() {...}`. At first glance this may appear to offer no advantage (other than suppressing the pesky warning) but in fact ensures that the function will throw asynchronously. As it stands, if `navigator`, or `navigator.serviceWorker` don't exist then `getUserSubscription()` will throw synchronously but with the `async` keyword, it will return a rejected Promise, thus the caller can expect a Promise to be returned under all cicumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `async` keyword in front of the function. Then `await` each `Promise` and return the result.

```
async function getUserSubscription() {
  const serviceWorker = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  const pushSubscription = await serviceWorker.pushManager.getSubscription();
  return pushSubscription;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I appreciate the answer!